# Switch to unity desktop envirnment in ubuntu 15.10 gnome

Tags: ubuntu-15.10

I just installed unity on ubuntu 15.10 (willy werewolf) using the command :

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

it went good, but I can't "activate" it, I still have gnome. normally I should find a way to change in the login screen but I can't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the [LightDM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) display manager and switching to it, then whilst logging in through it, you should be able to swap between Gnome and Unity.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:lightdm-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Then run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and select lightdm from the prompt:

[image]